# Microphone access FIrefox and Chrome on iOS 12

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, firefox

In Safari it can be accessed via navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(), but for Firefox and Chrome navigator.mediaDevices is undefined.
I know that Firefox is using WebView
[Firefox docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_for_iOS)
(Probably Chrome too), and it is supposed that these browsers will have the same javascript engine as Safari. Is this correct?

Maybe there is some HTML meta tag, which can enable access to media devices?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't access the microphone on firefox or chrome on iOS 15. This was asked 3 years ago, is there a solution now? It's strange, I can't find anything on the topic other than this SO post.

Comment: nevermind I need to allow access on the system settings first, so that permission is requested in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still looks like that Apple has not given free the access to mediaDevices for other browser distributor on iOS (while it works on OSX for all browsers). By saying this not only microphone but also camera/video is not accessible for HTML pages.

I've done a lot of researches about this topic but couldn't find a clear statement or any other way how to do it in Chrome/FF on iOS 11.2+. Some information were just misleading.

I've just asked this question to the Mozilla community. Feel free to track it in hope for a clear answer: [question here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1239241)

Comment: Thanks! Will follow your Mozilla community question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't access the microphone on firefox or chrome on iOS 15. This was asked 3 years ago, is there a solution now? It's strange, I can't find anything on the topic other than this SO post.

Comment: nevermind I need to allow access on the system settings first, so that permission is requested in the browser.